# grabbing the newest file from a subset of the contents of a folder in bash

Tags: bash

I have a folder with such contents

```
nass@starmaze:~/audio_setup/scripts$ ls -l ../jmess/
total 32
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nass users 1573 Νοέ  16  2014 jmess_fxio56-78feedsHDA-play12.jmess
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nass nass  1573 Δεκ  13  2014 jmess_pb-2.jmess
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nass nass  1573 Δεκ  20  2014 jmess_pb-3.jmess
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nass nass  1939 Ιούν 12 13:05 jmess_starmazeOnMaster.jmess
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nass nass  2163 Δεκ  15  2014 jmess_starmazeOnMaster.jmess.bak1-art
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nass nass  2161 Δεκ  15  2014 jmess_starmazeOnMaster.jmess.bak2-bcr
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nass nass  2389 Δεκ  22  2014 jmess_starmazeOnMaster.jmess.bak3-hoo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nass nass  2163 Δεκ  15  2014 jmess_starmazeOnMaster.jmess.bak4-dsp
```

I want to be able to pick up the newest file, but only from the subset of files that do not contain the word "Master" in them. And I want to put that in a bash script.

So this

```
ls -t1 "${JCMESS_FOLDER}" | head -n1
```

provides the newest file in the folder , while this

```
ls -t1 "${JCMESS_FOLDER}"/!(*Master*) | head -n1
```

provides the newest file among the subset that I am interested in.

However, when I place the latter in a bash script as

```
$NEWEST_JCMESS_FILE=$( ls -t1 "${JCMESS_FOLDER}"/!(*Master*) | head -n1 )
```

it does not work:

```
./06.load_jcmess: command substitution: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./06.load_jcmess: command substitution: line 8: ` ls -t1 "${JCMESS_FOLDER}"/!(*Master*) | head -n1 )'
```

I am not sure what is wrong in this case and I ahve not been able to successfully find an answer for this.

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Don't use `ls` for this at all. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Also, all-caps names are reserved for built-in and system-impacting environment variables; using them for your own variables is bad form. See fourth paragraph of POSIX spec @ http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace.

Comment: BTW, be sure you're running `shopt -s extglob`. I wonder if perhaps you're assuming that because extglobs work in your interactive shell they're also on by default in scripts? Not so; they need to be enabled explicitly. (That's true in interactive shells too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003):

```
newest() {
  local candidate result=$1; shift    # start with first argument as candidate
  [[ -e $result ]] || return          # handle case where nothing matched

  for candidate; do                   # for loop default behavior is to loop over "$@"
    [[ $candidate -nt $result ]] && result=$candidate
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$result"
}

shopt -s extglob # enable extglobs, ie. !(...)
newest_file=$(newest "$JCMESS_FOLDER"/!(*Master*))
```

Comment: please add the "shopt -s extglob" as the necessary step to get the above code working.