# How to compare the modified dates of 3 or more files

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that accepts 3 or more filenames as arguments and outputs the newest file. I'm finding it hard to compare the arguments since essentially each argument has to be compared to all the others.

I've tried creating a for loop but I'm stuck on how to get the next value in the loop. i.e the next argument

Does anyone have any way to successfully compare all the arguments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grabbing the newest file from a subset of the contents of a folder in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469597/grabbing-the-newest-file-from-a-subset-of-the-contents-of-a-folder-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls -c file1 file2 file3... | head -n 1` does the trick.

> -c sort by ctime, newest first
>
> -t sort by modification time, newest first
>
> -u sort by access time, newest first

The newest file will be at line 1. Depending on your need, you may choose the desired one.

Comment: There are already multiple posts about finding the newest file in Bash. I flagged a duplicate candidate I think you can adapt to your specific problem without too much trouble.